# frequency tables by groups in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

Simple query

```
SELECT  [Dt]
      ,[CustomerName]
      ,[ItemRelation]
      ,[DocumentNum]
      ,[DocumentYear]
      ,[CustomerType]
  FROM [Action].[dbo].[promo_data]
```

How can i calculate frequency tables by groups

```
[CustomerName]+[ItemRelation]+[DocumentNum]+[DocumentYear]+[CustomerType]
```

To be more clear, as output i want

```
 [CustomerName] [ItemRelation]  [DocumentNum]   [DocumentYear]  [CustomerType]  count
           dix  11111              123             2017              FC    23
          5ive  2222               333              2018             OPT    123
```

I tried do that

```
  select count (distinct [CustomerName]
      ,[ItemRelation]
      ,[DocumentNum]
      ,[DocumentYear]
      ,[CustomerType]) from [Action].[dbo].[promo_data]
```

but got the error

```
Message 102, level 15, state 1, line 11
Invalid syntax near the construction ",".
```

How can i calculate frequency tables by groups?

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`

Comment: you had error. because, you used multiple columns in `count()` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT [CustomerName]
      ,[ItemRelation]
      ,[DocumentNum]
      ,[DocumentYear]
      ,[CustomerType]
      ,Count(*) as cnt
  FROM [Action].[dbo].[promo_data]
GROUP BY
      [CustomerName]
      ,[ItemRelation]
      ,[DocumentNum]
      ,[DocumentYear]
      ,[CustomerType]
```